# How to open a document on a network computer with a batch or Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch, remote, documents

I would like to open a document (OpenOffice) on a laptop from my desktop PC. I do not need a full remote desktop, only that the document opens itself on the remote computer.

Is there a way to do this with for instance a batch file, Powershell or by some other way?

Answer (score 0):

To open the document from the client is as simple as executing
`\\computer\share-name\folder\document` or perhaps
`word \\computer\share-name\folder\document` (or another editor or viewer).

From the server to cause the client to open the document is impossible.

Comment: Impossible? Really? So I can't run psxec on a server to run a program on a client?

Comment: @DavidPostill: I don't think that will help the poster, but I might be wrong, of course.